# Image getting blur in canvas zoom.min.js

Tags: jquery

I am using canvas for multiple image and using zoom.js and zoom.min.js when I drop image in canvas image getting blur and in my console following error is displaying :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of
>   undefinedzoom.min.js:18142 ZM.setStatuszoom.min.js:18697
>   ZM.updateControlszoom.min.js:18776
>   isIE.undefined.b.getContext.window.addEventListener.ZM.canvas.on.object:selectedzoom.min.js:6040
>   azoom.min.js:8595
>   fabric.Canvas.fabric.util.createClass.setActiveObjectzoom.min.js:8900
>   fabric.util.object.extend._beforeTransformzoom.min.js:8886
>   fabric.util.object.extend.__onMouseDownzoom.min.js:8749
>   fabric.util.object.extend._onMouseDown

Answer (score 0):

the problem is unactive is a jQuery object not a dom element reference